# Python ctypes: Python file object <-> C FILE *

Tags: python, ctypes

I am using ctypes to wrap a C-library (which I have control over) with Python. I want to wrap a C-function with declaration:

```
int fread_int( FILE * stream );
```

Now; I would like to open file in python, and then use the Python file-object (in some way??) to get access to the underlying FILE * object and pass that to the C-function:

```
# Python
fileH = open( file , "r")
value = ctypes_function_fread_int( ????? )
fileH.close()
```

Is the Python file <-> FILE * mapping at all possible?

Joakim

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've encountered the same problem.

Take a look at this file:

http://svn.python.org/projects/ctypes/trunk/ctypeslib/ctypeslib/contrib/pythonhdr.py

You can use PyFile_AsFile from it.

Comment: Thanks - that was a better solution than mine.

Comment: Unfortunately PyFile_AsFile doesn't exist in Python 3 C API.

Comment: @MikhailKorobov: I asked [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16130268/309483) to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 29):

A Python file object does not necessarily *have* an underlying C-level `FILE *` -- at least, not unless you're willing to tie your code to extremely specific Python versions and platforms.

What I would recommend instead is using the Python file object's `fileno` to get a file descriptor, then use `ctypes` to call the C runtime library's `fdopen` to make a `FILE *` out of *that*.  This is a very portable approach (and you can go the other way, too).  The big issue is that buffering will be separate for the two objects opened on the same file descriptor (the Python file object, and the C `FILE *`), so be sure to flush said objects as often as needed (or, open both as unbuffered, if that's more convenient and compatible with your intended use).

Comment: Thanks a lot -I had this feeling that the C-level FILE * would not be very robust. I did not know about the fileno attribute of the python file object - but that seems like a natural way to go.

Comment: I had a problem importing stdin/stdout/stderr from an SO, and there was no chance I was going to build-out a formal Structure. Your fdopen() suggestion saved me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `stdout`/`stdin`/`stderr`, you can import those variables from the standard C library.

```
libc = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('libc.so.6')
cstdout = ctypes.c_void_p.in_dll(libc, 'stdout')
```

Or, if you want to avoid using `void*` for some reason:

```
class FILE(ctypes.Structure):
    pass

FILE_p = ctypes.POINTER(FILE)

libc = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('libc.so.6')
cstdout = FILE_p.in_dll(libc, 'stdout')
```

Answer (score 2):

Well;

I tried the `fileno` based solution, but was quite uncomfortable with opening the file twice; It was also not clear to me how to avoid the return value from `fdopen()` to leak.

In the end I wrote a microscopic C-extension:

```
static PyObject cfile(PyObject * self, PyObject * args) {
    PyObject * pyfile;
    if (PyArg_ParseTuple( 'O' , &pyfile)) {
       FILE * cfile = PyFile_AsFile( pyfile );
       return Py_BuildValue( "l" , cfile );
    else
        return Py_BuildValue( "" );
}
```

which uses `PyFile_AsFile` and subsequently returns the `FILE *` pointer as a pure pointer value to Python which passes this back to C function expecting `FILE *` input. It works at least.

Joakim

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from [svplayer](http://www.salstar.sk/pub/svplayer/vlc.py)

```
import sys

from ctypes import POINTER, Structure, py_object, pythonapi


class File(Structure):
    pass

if sys.version_info[0] > 2:
    convert_file = pythonapi.PyObject_AsFileDescriptor
    convert_file.restype = c_int
else:
    convert_file = pythonapi.PyFile_AsFile
    convert_file.restype = POINTER(File)

convert_file.argtypes = [py_object]

fp = open('path').fp
c_file = convert_file(fp)
```

Comment: Except this wrong: for py3k ``c_file`` will be ``int``, for py2k it will be ``FILE *``.

Comment: @mcepl you mind editing the answer to make it correct?

Comment: I believe the correct answer is in my solution above.

Answer (score 0):

Tried this:

```
#if PY_MAJOR_VERSION >= 3
    if (PyObject_HasAttrString(pyfile, "fileno")) {
        int fd = (int)PyLong_AsLong(PyObject_CallMethod(pyfile, "fileno", NULL));
        if (PyObject_HasAttrString(pyfile, "mode")) {
            char *mode = PyUnicode_AsUTF8AndSize(
                    PyObject_CallMethod(pyfile, "mode", NULL), NULL);
            fp = fdopen(fd, mode);
        }
        else {
            return PyErr_Format(PyExc_ValueError,
                    "File doesn’t have mode attribute!");
        }
    }
    else {
        return PyErr_Format(PyExc_ValueError,
                "File doesn’t have fileno method!");
    }
#else
    fp = PyFile_AsFile(pyfile);
#endif
```

It looks like it might be working.