# How to get the corresponding ctype for stdout on OS X using libc.dylib

Tags: python, macos, stdout, ctypes, libc

I was following some of the answers in [Python ctypes: Python file object <-> C FILE *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794309/python-ctypes-python-file-object-c-file) and I have encountered a problem. The following code:

```
from ctypes import *
libc = CDLL('libc.so.6')
cstdout = c_void_p.in_dll(libc, 'stdout')
```

Works without errors on my virtual machine running Ubuntu. However when I try to do the same thing on my MacbookPro running HighSierra, i.e:

```
from ctypes import *
libc = CDLL('libc.dylib')
cstdout = c_void_p.in_dll(libc, 'stdout')
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
ValueError: dlsym(0x7fff6bfc4728, stdout): symbol not found
```

I tried this using python2.7 and python3.5. With both of them I get no errors on Ubuntu and the previously mentioned error on OS X HighSierra.

The reason why I need this is because I am coding a Python wrapper for a C api, and in that C api there is a function that expects FILE* as an input argument, so I want to pass stdout to it.

Any help would be appreciated!

p.s. I would like to apologise for writing a new post, instead of commenting in the existing one, but I am a new user with only 35 reputation at the moment and I am not allowed to comment until I get at least 50 reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the stdio.h header on macOS:

`#define    stdout  __stdoutp`

Therefore your python code should do this instead:

`cstdout = c_void_p.in_dll(libc, '__stdoutp')`

I hope that the answer was helpful.